# Error-Unable to execute dex When using google play services in android?

Tags: android, admob, dex

I saw a video on how to use adMob in android and I Implemented it in the same way. But I get the following Display Error.

**Video Link:**
[[http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G-7_hYCqjs4][1]](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G-7_hYCqjs4%5d%5b1%5d)

**Error**

```
[2014-04-30 16:04:55 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/ads/AdRequest$ErrorCode;
[2014-04-30 16:04:55 - SSWallPaper] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/ads/AdRequest$ErrorCode;
```

Comment: Can you show us your implementation?

Comment: Actually I send Link of AdMob Video.
And I implement the code in Activity class which is,

`code`
import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;
AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);

And Import Google_PlayServices_lib from  Google Play Services.

1) Copy the Google Play Services in the My App in lib folder from Eclipse.

2) And then After Import the Google Play Service in the My App.